# cant git pull/push to github on remote server. although ssh-agent is enable and supposedly forwarding to the remote

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-agent

My config (ununtu 14.04 and the server ununtu 13.1)
following [this github tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding)
in my home (local) ~.ssh/config:

```
Host * 
  ForwardAgent yes
```

in my global (local) /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
Host *
  # various commented lines
  SendEnv LANG LC_*
  ForwardAgent yes
```

also tried the `forwardAgent` line in the sshd_config.
and in the remote sshd_config

this is the log (running ssh with -vvv flag) of the connection:
**Notice! I can ssh to the remote server! but ssh-agent - forwarding the ssh permissions from my computer to the remote don't work correctly so I can't git push/pull**

```
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alon/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/alon/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 54.187.97.141
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ip_address [ip_address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/alon/.ssh/nameofpem.pem" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/alon/.ssh/nameofpem.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alon/.ssh/nameofpem.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ip_address" from file "/home/alon/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/alon/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA .........
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ap_address" from file "/home/alon/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/alon/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'ip_address' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alon/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/alon/.ssh/nameofpem.pem (....),
debug2: key: /home/alon/.ssh/nameofpem.pem ((nil)), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/alon/.ssh/nameofpem.pem
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp ......
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA ......
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ip_address ([ip_address]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env JOB
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env INSTANCE
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env WEBIDE_JDK
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SESSION
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env NODE_PATH
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env PYCHARM_JDK
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_INIT
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY
debug3: Ignored env SESSIONTYPE
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = he_IL.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env GREP_OPTIONS
debug3: Ignored env GREP_COLOR
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME
debug3: Ignored env WORKON_HOME
debug3: Ignored env VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR
debug3: Ignored env PYENV_ROOT
debug3: Ignored env export
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

But in the remote server when I try to git push or just the github ssh test:

`ssh -T git@github.com`
I get a:
`Permission denied (publickey).`
Any clues? Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the server `sshd` is disallowing agent forwarding?

Comment: Also note that trying to put `forwardAgent` in `sshd_config` will not accomplish anything - `sshd_config` is different from `ssh_config`, and the structure, keywords, options, etc. are different. You need to look for `AllowAgentForwarding` in `sshd_config`...

Comment: @twalberg thanks. I know that actually. in the server sshd_config I got:
AllowAgentForwarding yes